# Restore big folder from trash with no space on HDD

Tags: delete, trash

I have accidentally deleted a big folder from my computer.

I have a backup of this folder in an external hard drive but it is going to be super slow to transfer it back to my computer.

I can't restore this folder because it occupies lot of space in the trash and then there is no space for the restore process.

Any hint on how to solve that?

Comment: The trash is usually stored in `/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash` so I guess you could just poke around in there and `mv` what you need back out?

Comment: @SHawarden Supersimple and perfectly working solution. Sometimes the answer is easier than it seems. If you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trash is usually stored in `/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash` so I guess you could just poke around in there and `mv` what you need back out?

Comment: When files was deleted from a mounted drive, '<THAT_DRIVE>/.Trash-1000' is another place for the trash.